# Cannot open modal dialog containing MS FlexGrid activex control

Tags: mfc, dialog, activex, msflexgrid

I am trying to open dialog containing MS FlexGrid ActiveX control using DoModal() from an ActiveX control project(OCX). I added member variable for the FlexGrid control and generated a wrapper class for it through wizard. But the dialog is not showing up after DoModal(). I noticed that the OnInitDialog() is not getting called. The dialog appears if I remove the MS FlexGrid control from the dialog.
I have no idea what did I miss.

Comment: If you remove just the control the dialog opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same thread that creates the controls/dialogs make sure that you initialize things with the following calls before creating any of the controls/dialogs.

```
AfxEnableControlContainer();
CoInitialize();
```

Comment: Thanks Erik. Added AfxEnableControlContainer() inside InitInstance() of my activex control. It worked.